# the datatime value displayed not correct on highchart

Tags: highcharts

first sorry for my poor english. 
I'm new with highcharts and trying to create a cool chart with highcharts.
The problem I meet is the datatime value and the xAxis value not the same when display on the chart.
      This's my data:

> [[1363663152000,1],[1363663153000,2],
>   [1363663154000,3],[1363663155000,4], 
>              [1363663156000,5],[1363663157000,6],[1363663158000,7],[1363663159000,8],
>              [1363663160000,9],[1363663162000,10],[1363663163000,11],[1363663164000,12],
>              [1363663165000,13],[1363663166000,14],[1363663167000,15],[1363663168000,16]]

```
  and this value: 
  1363663152000 --> Tue Mar 19 2013 10:19:12 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)
  ....
```

But for the xAxis: the x value is 03:19:12...

We can easy to see the difference here: 10:19:12 and 03:19:12
So, How can i format it from 03:19:12 --> 10:19:12?

Here's the online demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CAKQH/24209/. Any replies are welcome and I really appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `useUTC: false`, see: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.useUTC

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried this way and it the worked like a charm.

http://jsfiddle.net/gqXrs/2/